# Get users name by property using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get users by name property using Firebase, i don't know how to get users property like name and phone number, etc.
I only know how to get users property, but not inside users property, maybe you can understand from Firebase database below.

[image: Firebase database]

this is my code

```
private TextView profileName, profilePhoneno;
private ImageView profilePic;
private TextView emailname;


private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;

....
....

profilePic = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_imageView);

profileName = findViewById(R.id.profile_name_textView);

profilePhoneno = findViewById(R.id.profile_phoneno_textView);
emailname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewEmailAdress);

databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();
        
storageReference.child("users").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("profile pict").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Glide.with(context)
                        .load(uri)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_all_inclusive)
                        .dontAnimate()
                        .into(profilePic);
                    
                }
            });
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            startActivity(new Intent(context ,SignInActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
final FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    ItemsUser userProfile = dataSnapshot.getValue(ItemsUser.class);
                    profileName.setText(userProfile.getUserName());
                    profilePhoneno.setText(userProfile.getUserPhoneno());
                    emailname.setText(user.getEmail());
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled( DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, databaseError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data from the current user within the `/users/$uid` node, you'd do:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
usersRef.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ...
```

If you want to get the data for all users, that'd be:

```
usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ItemsUser userProfile = userSnapshot.getValue(ItemsUser.class);
            ...
        }
```